# CSS class applied to all but first elements of an ng-repeat

Tags: html, css, angularjs

Having a `span` containing an `ng-repeat` I was wondering if it is possible to apply a CSS class to all but first elements of it.

For example,

```
<span ng-repeat="row in element.Parameters track by $index" class="awesome-css-class">
      {{element.Parameters[$index]}}
</span>
```

My CSS class is

```
.awesome-css-class {
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

I tried with this method but apparently it doesn't work

```
.awesome-css-class ul:not(:first-child){
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you show us the generated HTML? Your CSS selector would suggest a layout similar to this: https://jsfiddle.net/r6k0vnp7/1/

Comment: Use `first-of-type` instead of `first-child`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
<span ng-repeat="row in element.Parameters track by $index" ng-class="{ 'awesome-css-class': $index != 0 }">
      {{element.Parameters[$index]}}
</span>
```

Comment: Instead of `{{element.Parameters[$index]}}`, you can simply use `{{row}}` to display elements.

Answer (score 2):

You added a wrong `ul` in your syntax:

```css
.awesome-css-class:not(:first-child) {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="awesome-css-class">Element</div>
<div class="awesome-css-class">Element</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Apply the class only to the first element:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

```
<span ng-repeat="row in element.Parameters track by $index" ng-class="[$index===0 ? 'awesome-css-class' : '']">
  {{element.Parameters[$index]}}
</span>
```

Alternatively, use pure CSS:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Afirst-child

```
.awesome-css-class:first-child
{
    background:red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

***.awesome-css-class:not(:first-child)*** is what you want.
This will select all element with class **.awesome-css-class** except those which are first child

```css
.awesome-css-class:not(:first-child) {
 color: red;
}
```

```html
<span class="awesome-css-class">1111</span>
<span class="awesome-css-class">2222</span>
<span class="awesome-css-class">3333</span>
<span class="awesome-css-class">4444</span>
<span class="awesome-css-class">5555</span>
```